# jQuery dialog place a div above button

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am using jQuery dialog:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      resizable: false,
      modal: true,

       buttons: {
          "Copy": function (){


          },
          Cancel: function (){

          }
     },
     open: function () {

     }
  });
```

I am trying to place a div above the copy button (div needs to be exactly above and the same size as the button) but when I trace ui-button offset().left and ui-button offset().top in dialog open callback I get 0.

Can I position the button above it?

Comment: what is the purpose of this div?  This kinda sounds like an XY problem...

Comment: I am trying to place a flash movie so I can have clipboard capability. I have searched for html5 solutions for clipboard but I havent found any that works on all browsers.